# Serialisation of public final fields

Tags: java, serialization, final

I'm using a simple struct where I store readonly values (like properties with no setter in C#). To achieve this I'm using `public final int test=42;`.

For some reasons I want to allow to serialize this class. I'm using this code:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException {
    oos.writeInt(test);
}
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws IOException {
    test=ois.readInt();
}
```

The last one does not work because the field test is final how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you actually need to customize serialization with `writeObject()`/`readObject()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to modify the value of `test`

```
// Get the Class object for the class of which test is a field
Class<?> myClass = MyClass.class;

// We will need to set test as accessible so as to change it's value
// Get the Field object for test
Field testField = myClass.getDeclaredField("test");
// Save the current accessibility of test
boolean wasAccessible = testField.isAccessible();
// Mark test as accessible
testField.setAccessible(true);
// Set the value of test for this instance of MyClass
int newTestValue = 42;
testField.setInt(this, newTestValue);
// Restore the accesibility of test to it's original
testField.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
```

The above assumes that your application has the permissions given by the `SecurityManager` to use reflection. If it does not, the `SecurityManager` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

`readObject` should always start with `defaultReadObject` or `readFields`; `writeObject` with `defaultWriteObject` or `putFields`. `defaultReadObject` will set the `final` field for you.

If you want to use `readFields`, then either remove the `final`, or stash in a temporary field and implement `readResolve` (note the original object will still be available to interested parties). Generally you really don't want to resort to the likes of `sun.misc.Unsafe`.

(The new Java Memory Model (JMM) introduce in J2SE 5.0 (and implemented in JDK 1.4) gives more liberties in the way final field can be optimised. In the example code of the question, the field is initialised with a *compile-time constant* expression. As such I'd expect it to be inlined (not tested).)

Comment: This is the right way to manage final fields and serialization. Using reflection is overkill and susceptible to not working in some setups.

Comment: This is certainly the better idea, but do note that `defaultReadObject` and `defaultWriteObject` use reflection under the hood as well (including a lot of caching and things you probably couldn't be bothered with).

Answer (score 0):

firstly, a `public final` primitive constant can be made `public static final` and doesn't need to be serialised because its always the same value.

However, say you have a field which is set by a constructor can can be different.

```
int test=ois.readInt();
Field testField = getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
testField.setAccessible(true);
testField.set(this, test);
```

Note: security managers often doesn't allow this if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Does the value of this `final` field change for each object or is it the same for all objects? i.e. is it set at the constructor or the field declaration level? If it stays the same, the simplest solution here would be to make it `static` and do away with the extra overhead of reading and writing the "read-only" values. Also, is it mandatory for you to provide the `readObject` and `writeObject` implementations rather than relying on the default mechanism?